# How to solve error code 403 while deploying Java code from Eclipse to AWS Lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy Java code from Eclipse to AWS Lambda.I have created IAM role and S3 bucket on US-Oregon datacenter. I can see IAM role being picked from the datacenter when I am trying to deploy from Eclipse, but it is neither showing me the S3 bucket I have created, nor it is allowing me to create new. It is showing below message - 
    
`Failed to load bucket in US West (Oregon): com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access 
     Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 97DD6E6753642878; 
     S3 Extended Request ID: 
     JpOEYYT1HCE4f7spDBeAmYhTbCIyXUXS3qQP5wtm1XEU+mPHDoaUFp9CUSC/d0WZu7ZFBcr+YAI=), S3 Extended Request 
     ID: JpOEYYT1HCE4f7spDBeAmYhTbCIyXUXS3qQP5wtm1XEU+mPHDoaUFp9CUSC/d0WZu7ZFBcr+YAI=.`

I have made the bucket policy public by writing below.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1234567890123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::srilambdabucket1/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::srilambdabucket1/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can you please advise, how can I solve the error? I am new to AWS.

Comment: please, show us how you are trying to do the deploy? Show us the command. Besides that, the Role is associated correctly to the user?

Comment: You are denying  `s3:PutObject` (uploading to your bucket) to everyone ("Principal": "*",). Does it all work without this policy?

Comment: I am following this URL to implement - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/lambda-tutorial.html. I have now updated policy description as {
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::srilambdabucket1/*"
        }  . Though it is still not working